# How to get data between two dates using a Query in Access 2016

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```
SELECT SignIn.VisitorFirstName, SignIn.VisitorLastName, SignIn.SignInDateTime
FROM SignIn
WHERE (((SignIn.[Complete])=Yes)) AND SignIn.SignInDateTime between #08/08/2016# and #08/10/2016#
```

The SignInDateTime is a Date/Time in MS Access 2016

The data in the field looks like **8/1/2016 12:30:11 PM**

I am trying to find records between dates (not really caring about the time)

Comment: What does the code above do now ? Are you sure with your date format (DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY) ?

Comment: NO errors but returns 0 lines. I verified the table having rows with entries on 8-1-2016 to 8-10-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, format the `SignInDateTime` first then place your criteria on the formatted datetime

```
SELECT SignIn.VisitorFirstName, SignIn.VisitorLastName, SignIn.SignInDateTime
FROM SignIn
WHERE (((SignIn.Complete)=Yes) AND ((Format([SignInDateTime],"Short Date")) Between #8/8/2016# And #8/10/2016#));
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the function datevalue() for query's.